# list of lists of dictionaries?

Tags: list, dictionary

I need to create a structure, in my mind similar to an array of linked lists (where a python `list = array` and `dictionary = linked list`). I have a list called `blocks`, and this is something like what I am looking to make:
`blocks[0] = {dictionary},{dictionary},{dictionary},...`

`blocks[1] = {dictionary},{dictionary},{dictionary},...`

etc..

currently I build the blocks as such:
`blocks = []`

`blocks.append[()]`

`blocks.append[()]`

`blocks.append[()]`

`blocks.append[()]`

I know that must look ridiculous. I just cannot see in my head what that just made, which is part of my problem. I assign to a block from a different list of dictionary items. Here is a brief overview of how a single block is created...

`hold = {}`

`hold['file']=file`

`hold['count']=count`

`hold['mass']=mass_lbs`

`mg1.append(hold)`
  ##this append can happen several times to `mg1`

`blocks[i].append(mg1[j])`

##where `i` is an index for the block I want to append to, and `j` is the list index corresponding to whichever dictionary item of `mg1` I want to grab.

The reason I want these four main indices in `blocks` is so that I have shorter code with just the one list instead of `block1` `block2` `block3` `block4`, which would just make the code way longer than it is now.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific about what exactly the question you want answered is? Are you looking for implementation code, do you have some that you're not sure about, or do you have some code using this pattern that you want refactored to use this structure?

Comment: `blocks.append[()]` does not make sense in python. `blocks.append([])` makes sense.

Comment: So what's the problem? :)

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I actually did ([]) in the code. Just reversed it here. What I want is a list of four elements, each which houses its own list of dictionaries. As it is now, I need to access all of the 'count' items in a blocks index, but I keep getting syntax errors. I'm assuming that my current way of creating blocks is incorrect.

Comment: Well, if your dicts are named `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, then it would be `blocks = [[a], [b], [c], [d]]`. I'm not sure I fully understand what exactly you're trying to accomplish however. It would be good to include some code using this hypothetical structure so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: I thought I already did include code. I showed how I created the structure completely.

Comment: You haven't included code _using_ the structure that's actually giving you the problems. As such, we can only guess what troubles you're having - not solve them.

Comment: My only problem is that I don't think this way of creating the structure is the best way. From what I would like, I'm just wondering how people would create this sort of thing: a list of 4 elements -- each element is a list of dictionary items.

Comment: Is this a list of four _dictionaries_, or a list of four _lists of items_ where each list happens to contain the values of a dictionary? Or is it a list of four _lists of unrelated dictionaries_?

Comment: it's a list of four lists of unrelated dictionaries, I suppose. The dictionary keywords are all the same, but the entries may vary between the lists. I may just change to multiple lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, going off of what was discussed in the comments, you're looking for a simple way to create a structure that is a list of four items where each item is a list of dictionaries, and all the dictionaries in one of those lists have the same *keys* but not necessarily the same *values*. However, if you know exactly what keys each dictionary will have and that never changes, then it might be worth it to consider making them classes that wrap dictionaries and have each of the four lists be a list of objects. This would be easier to keep in your head, and a bit more Pythonic in my opinion. You also gain the advantage of ensuring that the keys in the dictionary are static, plus you can define helper methods. And by emulating the methods of a container type, you can still use dictionary syntax.

```
class BlockA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary = {'file':None, 'count':None, 'mass':None }
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dictionary)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.dictionary[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.dictionary:
            self.dictionary[key] = value
        else:
            raise KeyError
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.dictionary)

block1 = BlockA()
block1['file'] = "test"
block2 = BlockA()
block2['file'] = "other test"
```

Now, you've got a guarantee that all instances of your first block object will have the same keys and no additional keys. You can make similar classes for your other blocks, or some general class, or some mix of the two using inheritance. Now to make your data structure:

```
blocks = [ [block1, block2], [], [], [] ]
print(blocks) # Or "print blocks" if you're not using Python 3.x
blocks[0][0]['file'] = "some new file"
print(blocks)
```

It might also be worthwhile to have a class for this blocks container, with specific methods for adding blocks of each type and accessing blocks of each type. That way you wouldn't trip yourself up with accidentally adding the wrong kind of block to one of the four lists or similar issues. But depending on how much you'll be using this structure, that could be overkill.